# Changing borderStyle with javascript DOM1

Tags: javascript, dom, border, getelementsbytagname

I just need the images to appear with a 2px, green, solid border once the images have loaded on the page. I have this:

```
img = getElementsByTagName("img");

for(i = 0; i < img.length; i++)
{
    img[i].style.borderStyle = "solid";
    img[i].style.borderWidth = "2px";
    img[i].style.borderColor = "green";
}
```

But nothing is happening... what am I missing?

Comment: I looks like you are missing "document." from getElementsByTagName unless you have created a short-cut variable for it?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you go with only with css?

```
img {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: This is a homework assignment that I'm struggling with... has to be done in DOM1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of changing the style using javascript to assign the style values

CSS

```
div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Javascript

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var length = elements.length;
var element;

for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    element = elements[i];
    element.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    element.style.borderWidth = "2px";
    element.style.borderColor = "green";
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Dt39r/)

Although the same could be achieved with just a CSS definition

CSS

```
div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-colour: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Dt39r/)

Comment: This is a homework assignment that I'm struggling with and the way I've done it is the way we were taught in class and now it's not working... I must use DOM1 to do this. Oh well, I'm sure he'll re-explain it in class.

Comment: Primarily the only thing stopping your code from working is the missing "document." from getElementsByTagName My example is just your code but cleaned up and optimised a little.